# expo typeerror: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expomodulescore.nativemodulesproxy.exponentconstants')

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I suddenly got an issue while running my `react-native` `expo` project.  It was working perfectly for a week but now I am getting an error

> "expo typeerror: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expomodulescore.nativemodulesproxy.exponentconstants')".

I've tried a lot but haven't fixed the issue. Can anyone tell me how can I fix this problem.
[Click to see screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtDbo.png)